# Hide element in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to hide this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rrad.jpg

What should I add in custom CSS?

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you need to read about how to ask question here.

Answer (score 1):

In your css file:

```
#banner-694641362 {
  display: none; 
}
```

*Tip:* You also can use `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

`display: hidden` makes an element invisible, but it still affects the rendering of surrounding elements. `display: none` removes the element from the document flow, so it doesn't affect other elements' rendering.

Answer (score 0):

`display: none;`

That will stop it from being shown

Comment: I know "display: none;" but for what should I use it?